# how to echo key name and key value from json decode in laravel blade

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new to laravel

I have a form. I get data from user and save it as json encoded string in DB. This is my laravel controller code.

```
public function order_requirements(Request $request)
 {   
     // Get the currently authenticated user...
     $user = Auth::user();
     $order_number = request('order_number');
     $orderData = Orders::whereOrder_number($order_number)->first();
     if($orderData['buyer_id'] == $user['id']){
          
        $orderData->order_requirements = json_encode($request->all());
        $orderData->save();
        return json_encode($request->all());
 
     }       

 }
```

I can successfully save the incoming order requirements to DB. It is working well. once I saved to DB
the data looks like this in DB

```
{"_token":"dq2zJU03UjxK1F2tAaXSu8gujUwElv7PkXhLipEY","order_number":"W1622543566X1","logo_name":"dd","logo_slogan":"love chicken","business_description":"chicken","styles":"red color"}
```

Now I want to show these details in a order page like this

```
order_number:W1622543566X1,
logo_name:dd,
logo_slogan:love chicken,
```

like this however I have many different forms, the key name is different form each other.

so my idea is to access key name and then key value. I can access values in laravel blade like this. but I can't get key names.

```
 @foreach (json_decode($orderData->order_requirements ,true) as $details)
     {{$details}},    
    @endforeach
```

in above code, `$orderData` is the returned `DB array` and the `order_requirements` field contains the `json encoded` data I saved.

with foreach loop above, what I get is this.

```
dq2zJU03UjxK1F2tAaXSu8gujUwElv7PkXhLipEN, W1622543566X1, dd, love chicken, chicken, red color,
```

but I want to print key name before each value like this

```
order_number:W1622543566X1,
logo_name:dd,
logo_slogan:love chicken, ...
```

how can I do this? I have no idea to continue beyond this, please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? As `json_decode` returns an array, you can use it like you can use any other array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the key in your `foreach` call and use `<br />`:

```php
@foreach (json_decode($orderData->order_requirements ,true) as $key => $value)
     {{$key}}:{{$value}},<br />  
@endforeach
```